# MySQL limit inside of the subquery produces error

Tags: mysql

I'm receiving:

`[Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

While executing the following query:

```
UPDATE account.account
SET STATUS = 'BLOCK'
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT
            p.account_id
        FROM
            log.log
        LEFT JOIN player.player p ON (p.id = log.who)
        WHERE
            vnum = 71054
        AND how = 'BUY'
        GROUP BY
            log.`who`
        HAVING
            COUNT(log.who) > 2
        LIMIT 10
    );
```

Is there a posibility to rewrite this query so MySQL could execute it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to join against a subquery rather than use an `IN()`. The `INNER JOIN` will only return rows in `account` matching ids from the limited subquery. It is then possible to do the `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause.

```
Update 
  account.account AS account
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.account_id
        FROM
            log.log
            LEFT JOIN player.player p ON (p.id = log.who)
        WHERE
            vnum = 71054
            AND how = 'BUY'
        GROUP BY log.`who`
        HAVING COUNT(log.who) > 2
        LIMIT 10 
   ) subq ON account.id = subq.id
SET STATUS='BLOCK'
```

To verify the rows that would be modified, use a `SELECT` first:

```
SELECT
  account.*
FROM 
  account.account
  INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                p.account_id
            FROM
                log.log
                LEFT JOIN player.player p ON (p.id = log.who)
            WHERE
                vnum = 71054
                AND how = 'BUY'
            GROUP BY log.`who`
            HAVING COUNT(log.who) > 2
            LIMIT 10 
       ) subq ON account.id = subq.id
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know, thats why I have been waiting here `:P`.